# Find $S=\bigg\lfloor {\sum_{k=1}^{99} \frac{1}{\sqrt{r_k-1}}} \bigg \rfloor$

Tags: linear-algebra, summation, contest-math, ceiling-and-floor-functions

If $$ \prod_{k=1}^{99} (x+k) = \sum_{k=0}^{99} a_k \cdot x^k$$

Also $$ M= \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{99} k\cdot a_k}{100!}= \sum_{i=1}^{99} \frac{1}{r_i}$$

Where $r_i<r_j$, $∀$ $i<j$. Then find $S$ which is given by
$$S=\bigg\lfloor {\sum_{k=1}^{99} \frac{1}{\sqrt{r_k-1}}} \bigg \rfloor$$

**My approach:**

I don't know what's the role of $r_i<r_j$, $∀$ $i<j$.

So, I wrote $$\frac{1}{v_k}= \frac{k\cdot a_k}{100!}$$

Because,$${\sum_{k=1}^{99} \frac{1}{\sqrt{r_k-1}}}={\sum_{k=1}^{99} \frac{1}{\sqrt{v_k-1}}}$$

Which gave, $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{v_k-1}}= \sqrt{ \frac{k\cdot a_k}{100!-k\cdot 
 a_k}} $$

But now I am unable to solve this summation series. Could someone help me out?

Comment: Where did this problem come from?  Are the $r_k$ supposed to be integers?

Comment: @RobertIsrael no $r_k$ is not necessarily integer . This problem was from INMO shortlisted which had no solutions available online.

Comment: Numerically, $\lfloor \sum_k  1/\sqrt{v_k - 1} \rfloor = 10$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael can you prove it?

Comment: If there are no more restrictions on $r$, then they can be just about anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that the $r_i$ are integers such that $1<r_1<\ldots<r_{99}$.

The statement is very enigmatic, but I think that I have a solution.

Call $P$ the polynomial given by
$$P(x) = \prod_{k=1}^{99}(x+k) = \sum_{k=0}^{99} a_k x^k.$$
Then
$$P'(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{99}\prod_{k \ne i}(x+k) = \sum_{k=0}^{99}k a_k x^{k-1}.$$
By division, if $x \notin \{1,\ldots,99\}$,
$$\frac{P'(x)}{P(x)} = \sum_{i=1}^{99}\frac{1}{x+i} = \frac{\sum_{k=0}^{99}k a_k x^{k-1}}{\prod_{k=1}^{99}(x+k)}.$$
Applying these two equalities to $x=1$ yields
$$\frac{P'(1)}{P(1)} = \sum_{i=1}^{99}\frac{1}{1+i} = \frac{\sum_{k=0}^{99}k a_k}{100!}$$

The only choice of integers such that $1<r_1<\ldots<r_{99}$ and
$$\sum_{i=1}^{99}\frac{1}{r_i} = \frac{\sum_{k=0}^{99}k a_k}{100!}$$
are given by $r_i=i+1$ for every $i$. Indeed, the condition $1<r_1<\ldots<r_{99}$ forces $r_i \ge i+1$ for every $i$, and if one of this inequality was strict, we would get $\sum_{i=1}^{99}\frac{1}{r_i} < \frac{\sum_{k=0}^{99}k a_k}{100!}$.

Hence the quantity to be computed is $S = \lfloor \sum_{i=1}^{99}\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}\rfloor$.

Since the map $x \mapsto x^{-1/2}$ is decreasing on $\mathbb{R}_+$, we have for every $i \ge 1$
$$\int_i^{i+1} x^{-1/2}dx < i^{-1/2} < \int_{i-1}^i x^{-1/2}dx.$$
By summation over $i \in \{2,\ldots,99\}$,
$$17 < 2\sqrt{100}-2\sqrt{2} = \int_2^{100} x^{-1/2}dx < \sum_{i=2}^{99} i^{-1/2} < \int_1^{99} x^{-1/2}dx = 2\sqrt{99}-2\sqrt{1} < 18,$$
so
$$18 < \sum_{i=1}^{99} i^{-1/2} < 19.$$
Hence $S=18$.

Comment: How did you found $\lfloor \sum_{i=1}^{99}\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}\rfloor$?

Comment: In completed a bit my answer.

Comment: So, we can't find exact answer?

Comment: We need sharper bounds. My impression is that applying Euler Mac Laurin formula should give the answer.

Comment: The bound is inaccurate for the initial values, so just take the sum of the first few terms and apply the integral.

Comment: @Calvin Lin. Thank you, it provides the final step of the solution. Isolating the first term $1^{-1/2}=1$ is sufficient.